# unable to split string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <table border="0"  class="commentbox">
   <tr>
     <td>
          <div id="comment-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778"></div>
         <input type="button" class='btnReply' id="reply-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778" value="Reply"/>

     </td>
 </tr>
</table>

  $(".commentbox .btnReply").live("click", function () {
            //  $(this).hide();
            // i = 1;
            id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
            alert(id);
            var strDiv = 
             "<input type='text' class='txtCmnt' id='txtReply-" + id + "' /> 
        <input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + id + "' /> ";
            $("#comment-" + id).append(strDiv);


        });
```

i want the f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778 to come after split rather alert is giving
 **f78d0b00**

I have tried to change id = comment_ f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778  and split

```
id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1],but it doesnt work.
```

**Edited**

**Input** - container-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778

**Output** after split f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778

Comment: What string is your input, and what's your expected output?

Comment: What is returned in `<%:rid %>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly convoluted means of achieving your end-result:

```
// splits the supplied string by the hyphen '-' character
var string = 'comment-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778'.split(/-/);
    // removes the zeroeth/first element from the string array
    string.shift();
    // joins the remaining elements from the string back together
var newString = string.join('-');
console.log(newString);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uWCgg/1/).

---

**Edited** to turn the above into a function:

```
function splitString(haystack, needle){
    if (!needle || !haystack){
        return false;
    }
    var string = haystack.split(needle);
    string.shift();
    return string.join(needle);
}

// the first argument is the string you want to work on,
// the second is the character you want to split on
// f is the variable that will hold the new string
var f = splitString('comment-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778','-');
console.log(f);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uWCgg/2/).

References:

- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: +1 for brevity. @prerna, he is splitting the string into an array first, then removing the first element of the array [using array.shift()] and then simply joining the array into a string again :)

Comment: var id = $(this).attr("id").split(/-/);
                alert(id);
                string.shift();
                var newString = string.join('-');                    
                alert(newString);It is not printing anything

Comment: var id = $(this).attr("id").split("/-/");
                alert(id);
                id.shift();
                var newString = id.join('-');
                alert(newString); Then also newString is not printing anthing

Comment: var id = splitString($(this).attr('id'),'-'); is also showing javascript error

Comment: @prerna How is this possible that all examples here works for everyone, but you?

Comment: i am unable to find the error alert(id )is printing but not alert(newString )is not

Comment: yes split(-) works thks but http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uWCgg/4/ given is not woking by function it is

Comment: Thks for your great explaination,it helped a lot

Comment: $(".commentbox .btnSave").live("click", function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
                alert(id);
                id.shift();
                alert(id);
                var newString = id.join("-");
                alert(newString);    });I am unable to use join("-") alert is giving f78d0b00,a008,473d,b647,a4a103ee3778

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10361/discussion-between-prerna-and-david-thomas)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JPPHm/5/ I am basically appending guid to id ,i want to split guid from it why in save button it is not working but in reply button it is

Comment: Do continue this in chat when you can. The comments are getting rather unwieldy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is not going to change then how bout using the substring function instead?

```
var str = "comment-f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778";
var subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("-") + 1);

alert(subStr);
```

This returns: f78d0b00-a008-473d-b647-a4a103ee3778
Here s a jsfiddle for the same
http://jsfiddle.net/M2Ywy/

If it works for you then your code would look like this

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var subStr = id.substring(str.indexOf("-") + 1);

alert(subStr);
var strDiv =
"<input type='text' class='txtCmnt' id='txtReply-" + id + "' /> <input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + id + "' /> ";

$("#comment-" + subStr).append(strDiv);
```

Comment: @prerna, you should explain yourself when asking something. Anyways, if the prefix string is static then you can. Otherwise, `indexOf` is your best choice. Although, splitting + joining back is another choice.

Comment: alert is  not printing anything

Answer (score 0):

### *[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNrfJ/2/)*

This should do it:

```
 var id = '';
 var strDiv = '';
 $(".btnReply").live("click", function () {
            //  $(this).hide();
            // i = 1;
            id = $(this).prev('div').attr("id").split("comment-")[1];
            alert(id);
            strDiv = "<input type='text' class='txtCmnt' id='txtReply-"+ id +"' /><input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-"+ id +"' />";
            $("div[id*="+id+"]").append(strDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, might be a longer version, but just 3 lines strong.
Just `split()` the string via the hyphens `"-"` and then splice the first index and then rejoin the whole string using the `join()` method

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eE48z/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".commentbox .btnReply").click(function(){
var jid = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
jid.splice(0,1);
var id=jid.join("-");
alert(id);
var strDiv = "<input type='text' class='txtCmnt' id='txtReply-" + id + "' /><input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + id + "' /> ";
        $("#comment-" + id).append(strDiv);
    });
});
```