# join method is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPPHm/5/)

```
$(".commentbox").on("click",".btnSave",function(){


         var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
            alert(id);
            id.shift();
            alert(id);
            var newString = id.join('-');
            alert(newString);


   });       
});​
```

Input is `btnSave-88eC4B8D2-8F96-4EB5-B42E-08C540D7F171`

Output :`88eC4B8D2,8F96-4EB5,B42E,08C540D7F171`

Whereas it works fine for `btnReply` button Why
Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a trick question ? :)

---

The problem is with this line of code

```
<input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + id + "' /> "
```

Here id passed is actually `id="btnSave-88C4B8D2,8F96,4EB5,B42E,08C540D7F171"` because id is an array and  that array got converted to a comma separated string because you set it as string attribute. Now you call split(-) on that string which gives you "btnSave" and "88C4B8D2,8F96,4EB5,B42E,08C540D7F171". Now you `shift` and remove the btnSave leaving the single member "88C4B8D2,8F96,4EB5,B42E,08C540D7F171" and then you call join("-") on that single string which doesn't change a thing at all. So, all you have to do is change the above shown like like this

```
<input type='button' class='btnSave' value='Save' id='btnSave-" + newString + "' /> "
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/XHr6e/

Comment: yes you are right,I made a silly mistake ,I forgot to change id to newString,thks

Answer (score 0):

One of the weird issues I have encountered, but escaping the  `-` fixes the problem.

```
var newString = id.join('\-');
```

Usage: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XSDWP/)

```
$(".commentbox").on("click",".btnSave",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
        id.shift();
        var newString = id.join('\-');
        alert(newString);
   });       
});​
```

Comment: pal, why are you escaping the join char? what use? and it doesn't work if you dont escape? wondering..

Comment: It seems to be taking `-` as negation may be. See, the demo.

Comment: I didn't downvote.. but this is not correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join did you try OPs fiddle and could make it work?

Comment: @naveen, Yes, I did try a similar code from OP, just check it

Comment: The main problem with the code, [so far as I can tell](http://jsfiddle.net/JPPHm/3/), is that after `newString` is defined s/he refers to the `id` variable instead of the `newString` variable.

Comment: -1:@Starx: its ok to commit a mistake, the -1 is for persisting with that mistake

Comment: There's no need for a downvote. Starx did the best he could with the code he had, I think. I only knew about the mistake because I helped to put [together the code in a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267008/unable-to-split-string-in-jquery/10267106#10267106), and have spent some time helping to try and straighten out the mistakes.

Comment: @David Thomas: I disagree. OP has pasted the full code as fiddle at the top of the answer. and the vote is locked anyway.

Comment: Ah! I saw another name attached to an edit, I hadn't realised that it had been added earlier. Ah, well.

Comment: @David Thomas: also Starx must show some responsibility. he is a trusted member at SO. I spent a good lot of time at MDN to check whether one would escape a join `separator`. You see people check reputations and believe that would be true. Starx, no offense pal.

Comment: @naveen, Actually OP pasted the fiddle much after I answered. And about the responsibility part as @ David said I did the best with the content I was given.